# Looking for openings by pawn structure

Tags: opening, pawn-structure

Sometimes when playing Alekhine defense Scandinavian Variation, I get this kind of pawn structure :

```
8/p6p/6p1/2p1p3/2PpP1P1/Pp1P4/1P6/8 w - - 1 29
```

I am very comfortable playing as black with this structure, but there is it not the most common structure I would get in Alekhine, so are there any openings which may result in this (or similar structure) ?

Comment: How on Earth do you go form an Alekhine to this?

Comment: @David First you sacrifice both Kings...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're mainly referring to the central pawn mass - wanting to get a structure with a Black pawn on b3 seems too specific.

In general, it's much harder to deliberately maneuver the game into a line where you are the person with the pawn on d4 (or if you're playing White, with the pawn on d5). This is because you need to get your opponent to provoke your d-pawn forward with e4 and c4. If you liked playing the White side of that diagram, I would recommend playing the Czech Benoni *as Black* (i.e: 1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 c5 3.d5 e5 4.Nc3 d6).

If you want a higher chance of getting the structure with c4-, d5-, and e4-pawns (so basically being on the flipped side of Black in that diagram), I'd recommend playing 1.d4 and 2.c4 as White. Your opponent could go into the aforementioned Czech Benoni (although it isn't very common), or they could play the King's Indian Defense. In that structure, Black often plays ...e5/...c5, and once in a while pushes both pawns (getting you into a situation you want).

I don't have much advice for how to get that structure as Black. You're at the mercy of your opponent to dictate the play. One of the most common ways I know of getting it is if White plays a reverse King's Indian, allowing you to push all your pawns with ...d5, ...c5, ...e5, but most people don't do this.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting opponent you have there, to let you get to that pawn formation. And yes, I said let, because the two most often played moves in that variation (e5 and exd5) both render that pawn structure pretty much impossible. I used to play the White side of that a lot, myself, but I always responded to Black's ...d5 with d4 (love making Alekhine players play the pawn-up side of a gambit).

Don't blame you for being comfortable playing that position. Everything unseen being equal, Black has all the winning chances there.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure about the FEN, particularly the black pawn on b3? Also a white pawn is missing. Ignoring the a-b and g-h pawns and focusing on the central pawns....

It is very unusual to get that much space as a black player. So no, unless your opponent plays particularly passively, you are not going to get such structure in any opening.

The structure resembles some Kings Indian structures, but with reversed colors. If you could express what paricular features you like about such structure, apart from the (unrealistic to get) space advantage, perhaps something could be suggested.